# Rails 3: Model After Filter causing infinite loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, infinite-loop, after-save

I have the following After Filters:

User Model:

```
  def check_for_custom_district
    unless self.custom_district.blank?
      district = District.new(:name => custom_district, :state_id => state_id, :school_type_id => school_type_id)

      if district.save(false)
        school = School.new(:name => custom_school, :state_id => state_id, :country_id => 1, :source => "User")
        if school.save(false)
          district.schools << school
          update_attribute(:school_id, school.id)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def check_for_custom_school
    if self.custom_district.blank? and self.custom_school.present?
      school = School.new(:name => custom_school, :state_id => state_id, :country_id => 1, :source => "User", :school_district_id => district_id)
      school.save(false)
      update_attribute(:school_id, school.id)
    end
  end
```

I ran some debugging to output the results to the console and the code is hitting the `check_for_custom_district` method and causing an infinite loop for some reason. Not sure how to stop this... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming it's an `after_save` filter.

So lets say you just saved your `model`.

It triggers the `after_save` filter. But, in your filter, you actually call `update_attribute(:school_id, school.id)`, which also saves the current model, which triggers your `after_save` filter again.

That's where your infinite loop is coming from.

One way to get around this might be not to use the `after_save` filter at all. For example, just re-implement the `save` method:

```
def save(*)
  # your custom logic goes here
  super
end
```